# Ocultar elemento que está adentro de "<script>"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen día a todos.
Tengo un problema, es que con "SINGLE HTML DOM" obtengo este script de una pagina web (Que no es mia) pero adentro de este script tiene una imagen que no deseo que se muestre. Hay alguna manera de hacerlo?
Probé con `img {display:none;}` con css y no funcionó. Este es el script:

```
<script type="63650c9ca0950a6ebdd0c7d1-text/javascript">
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "https://linkr&_c=1568740222570", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJUb29sYm94IERpZ2l0YWwgU0EiLCJhdWQiOiJ1bml0eS50YnhhcGlzLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTU2ODc0MDIxOSwiZXhwIjoxNTY4OTEzMDE5LCJjb3VudHJ5IjoiQVIiLCJsYW5ndWFnZSI6ImVzIiwiY2xpZW50IjoiOWQyOWEzNzIzZTk5MjVjMzc1NDc4ZTJjODhjYWM5NWYiLCJkZXZpY2UiOiJkM2JlY2ZlNwfwfw");
xhttp.send();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            var m3u8 = jsonResponse['entitlements'][2]['url'];
            var playerInstance = jwplayer("player");
            playerInstance.setup({
                file: m3u8,
                title: "Fox Sports en VIVO",
                description: "Descripcion a borrar",
                image: "https://IMAGEN-A-BORRAR.jpg",
                type: "hls",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                aspectratio: "16:9",
                autostart: false,
                cast: {},
              logo: {
    file: "LOGO-A-BORRAR",
    link: "LINK-A-BORRAR",
    position: "top-right",
    hide: 'false',
            linktarget: '_blank',
            hide: 'false',
  }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Como ven, ahi puse todo lo que tendria que borrar, editar u ocultar en la pagina web.

La imagen se muestra como background:

```
<div style="background-image:IMAGEN.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Probablemente no sea un <img> deberías inspeccionar el código y ver que es exactamente.

Comment: Ahí lo vi, es un `background-image` que está adentro de un `<div style="background-image:IMAGEN.jpg"></div>` hay alguna manera de ocultar eso?

Answer (score 1):

Siempre que NO esté dentro de un `<iframe>` Puedes seleccionar y cambiar los estilos de un elemento del DOM a partir de su `background-image` (siempre que este cargado) asi:

**HTML**

```
<div id="e" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0f0w.png"></div>
```

**JavaScript** (Importante: debe hacerse en el callback del ajax o cuando sea que cargue!!)

```
const element = document.querySelector('div[style*="imgur"]');

element.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
```

El ejemplo funcional aquí https://jsfiddle.net/kmox5vh9/

en este ejemplo uso la URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0f0w.png solo como ejemplo, y en `div[style*="imgur"]` *imgur* es solo para mostrar que es una parte de la url, podría ser toda.

Es probable que además del callback, tengas que esperar el load de algo mas, quizá algo como `jwplayer().onReady(function() { // código aqui });`